# Can't use this to point a selected element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this JS does not apply my class to the element please ?

```
<input type="password" name="customer-new-password" class="form-control">

<script>
if($("input[name='customer-new-password']").val()=='') {
    $(this).addClass('required');
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass('required');
}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: classname should be in double quotes. .addClass("required");

Comment: What do you think $(this) refers to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think $(this) would point to your selected object?

Try this instead:

```
var $input = $("input[name='customer-new-password']");
if($input.val()=='') {
    $input.addClass('required');
}
else {
    $input.removeClass('required');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(this)` has no context. Use `$('input[name="customer-new-password"]')` instead.

Comment: I do not want to repeat it each time.